# ORDER BY issue in Postgres (Heroku)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, heroku

The following code works for Postgres (Heroku):

```
 @messages = Message.select("DISTINCT
 ON (messages.conversation_id)
 *").where("messages.sender_id = (?) OR messages.recipient_id = (?)",
 current_user.id, current_user.id)
```

However, when attempting to order the results by appending `.order("messages.read_at DESC")` I receive the following error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (PGError: ERROR: column id_list.alias_0 does not exist)
```

In looking at the generated SQL, I see that an alias is being created around the ORDER BY statement when not asked for:

```
messages.recipient_id = (32))) AS id_list ORDER BY id_list.alias_0 DESC)
```

I've not been able to figure out a workaround short of using "find_by_sql" for the entire statement - which takes a heavy toll on the app.

Comment: Perhaps the `DISTINCT ON` has this side effect. I don't understand what this query is supposed to show. Neither why you have both `DISTINCT ON` and `GROUP BY`.

Comment: you are right, the GROUP BY code was unnecessary. updated question and error message to reflect this. this query returns messages grouped by their conversation_id, so that the last message in each conversation is shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't vote this, I only post because posting many lines in comments does not show very well.

I would write a "query that returns messages grouped by their conversation_id, so that the last message in each conversation is shown" like this:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM messages m
  JOIN 
    ( SELECT conversation_id
           , MAX(created_date) AS maxdate
      FROM messages
      WHERE ...
      GROUP BY conversation_id
    ) AS grp
    ON  grp.conversation_id = m.conversation_id
    AND grp.maxdate = m.created_date
ORDER BY m.read_at DESC
```

No idea how this can be done in Heroku or if it even possible, but it avoids the `DISTINCT ON`. If that's causing the error, it may be of help.

Comment: FYI: Heroku is just a Ruby/Rails hosting service, they use PostgreSQL 8 for shared databases and PostgreSQL 9 for dedicated databases. The trick is getting ActiveRecord to produce sensible SQL without doing the derived table by hand and using `IN`. Everyone keeps trying to reinvent SQL with an in-language API and they keep doing it badly.

Comment: @mu is too short: thnx for the info. So, this may be an ActiveRecord issue? How to translate the SQL to Activerecord?

Comment: this solution works (for both Postgres and SQLite) and its output is actually more exact than the code I had. I'll use it until a fix is found. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, this is really an ActiveRecord issue. One of these days we'll get an ORM that is smart enough to use SQL as its API :) I'm upvoting you even though you don't want it, often the only way to get ActiveRecord to behave sensibly is to push it out of the way and go straight to SQL.